# Appium Android Inspector can't inspect elements

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, android-testing, appium

I have Appium running against one of my Android apps on a Mac.

When I open the inspector, I see the preview window of the app, but I cannot click on anything in the preview window.  Also, there are no elements listed.

I've tried against an emulator, a genymotion virtual machine, and a real Android device with the same results.

When I flip the Appium switch to run against my iOS apps, all the elements load as expected, and I can interact with the preview window and record actions.

Does the inspector not work with Android??

I'm using Appium 0.12.3.

Comment: Could you let me know the android version you are using? and is there any error message appeared on starting the appium inspector session?

Comment: This question is almost 6 years old and I haven't used Appium in nearly as long.

Answer (score 0):

Inspector should work with android just like iOS but I have had better luck getting the ID and Name of the elements using the uiautomatorviewer that comes with the android SDK tools. Appium is good for getting the xpath but not much else IMO.

Also that version of appium you have is out of date. I think its up to 0.15.0 now

Comment: I haven't had time to try it with Android since 0.12.3 as I've been in iOS land for the last couple months.  I, too, have had much more success with the uiautomatorviewer =).

Comment: Perhaps its the configuration of the emulator causing the issue. Try different screen sizes and other options for the deivce

Comment: I've tried with genymotion, the built-in android emulator, and 2 or 3 real android phones.  However, as you pointed out, the last version I was able to try is pretty old.  I'll report back once I can try on 0.15.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with appium inspector then I used uiautomatorviewer and it's working great. uiautomatorviewer is better than appium inspector.